# How to share cloudformation output values external to AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a set of CloudFormation stacks which build up my back-end. My client application relies on some of the CloudFormation output values.

Is there a way to access (e.g. API) those values from a client application (e.g. a mobile app)?

Comment: The `DescribeStacks()` command can provide the `Outputs` of a stack. So, you can write code that retrieves these details, but it is up to you how to "provide" that information to your client applications.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no direct way to do this through Cloudformation, but you could write a custom resource that creates a config file on S3. You can then read the config file in your app.

As an example, take a look at the following aws sample template ->
https://s3.amazonaws.com/wildrydes-us-east-1/WebApplication/2_UserManagement/user-management.yaml

1. UpdateConfigFunction is the custom resource that creates a file on S3 Bucket as js/config.js
2. You can the use the custom resource and write the data you need (see UpdateConfig)

Hope this helps.